# How to evaluate this integral $\int_0^{35}xf(-7x)f(-3x)f(3x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I´m trying to resolve this

$I = \int_0^{35}xf(-7x)f(-3x)f(3x)dx$

if we know that

$f(x+y) = \frac{f(x)f(y)}{-3}$,

$\int f(x)dx = c -\frac{f(x)}{5}$

and $f(x) > 0$

I´ve tried to get f(x) in terms of x from second equation using integrations by parts like below

$ \int udv = uv - \int vdu$

then $u = f(x), du = df(x), dv = dx, v = x + k$

then $\int udv = f(x)(x+k)- \int (x+k)df(x)$

but I'm not going to any place doing that. Maybe someone could help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hint:- Note that $$f(3x)f(-3x)f(-7x)=f(-7x)\frac{f(0)}{-3}=\frac{f(-7x)}{9}$$

Comment: how do you get that $f(3x)f(-3x) = -1/3f(0)$ and that $f(0)=-1/3$?

Comment: I used the condition that  you mentioned for $f(x+y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting $x=y=0$ in $-3 f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ we get $0 =f(0)(f(0)+3)$, and thus $f(0)=0$ or $f(0) = -3$. But since $f(x) >0$ then $f(0)$ can't be defined. So the condition $f(x) >0$ clashes with the other properties.

So what inequality *can* happen? Given any $a$, notice that setting $y=x = \frac{a}{2}$ in $-3 f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ we get
$$
-3 f(a) = \left(f\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)^2
$$
Since $\left(f\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)^2 \ge 0$ as it's a number squared, and $-3 <0$, the above equality is only possible if $f(a) \le 0$ for all $a$.

This gives us $2$ possibilities, $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) <0$. Since $f(x) =0 $ implies that $$ \int_0^{35} x f(-7x) f(-3x) f(3x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^{35} x \cdot 0 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 \, \mathrm{d} x  \int_0^{35} 0 \, \mathrm{d} x =0$$ the only interesting case is if $f(x) <0$.

Recalling that $f(0)=0$ or $f(0) = -3$, if $f(x) \mathbin{\color{red}{<}}0$ then this forces $f(0)=-3$. We thus get
\begin{align}
\int_0^{35} x f(-7x) f(-3x) f(3x)\, \mathrm{d}x &=-3\int_0^{35} x f(-7x)\underbrace{f(-3x+3x)}_{f(0)}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
& \overset{\color{darkblue}{t=-7x}}{=} -\frac{9}{49} \int_{-245}^0 t \underbrace{\left( -\frac{f(t)}{5}\right)'}_{f(t)}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
& \overset{\text{IBP}}{=}-\frac{9}{49} \left(t \left(-\frac{f(t)}{5} \right)\Bigg\vert_{-245}^{0}  -  \int_{-245}^0 -\frac{f(t)}{5} \, \mathrm{d}t \right)\\
& =-\frac{9}{49} \left(-\frac{245}{5} f(-245)  + \frac{1}{5} \left(-\frac{f(t)}{5} \right)\Bigg\vert_{-245}^{0} \right)\\
& =-\frac{9}{1225} \left(3 - 1224 f(-245) \right)
\end{align}
Using differential equations you can simplify this further, since $f' = - \frac{f}{5}$ combined with $-3f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$ and $f<0$ give $f(x) = -3e^{-5x}$. This allows us to find the missing value $f(-245) = -3e^{-5(-245)} = -3e^{1225}$. We thus get the *final* final result as
$$
\int_0^{35} x f(-7x) f(-3x) f(3x)\, \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{27}{1225} \left(1 + 1224 e^{1225} \right)
$$
which agrees with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral_0%5E35+x+%28-3+e%5E%28-5+%28-7+x%29%29%29+%28-3+e%5E%28-5+%28-3+x%29%29%29+%28-3+e%5E%28-5+%283+x%29%29%29+dx+)'s value for the integral if we plug in $f(x) = -3e^{-5x}$ from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. a doubt. You use $f(-3x)f(3x) = f(-3x+3x)$. Is this then a know property like $f(ax)*f(bx)=f(ax+bx)$? And original evaluation is from 0 to 1/35, is a typo of me set from 0 to 35. I think then is an error in original problem set condition $f(x) > 0$

Comment: I used the property $f(\color{darkblue}{a}) f(\color{purple}{b}) =-3 f(\color{darkblue}{a}+\color{purple}{b}) $ that you mention in your question, choosing $\color{darkblue}{a} = \color{darkblue}{-3x}$ and $\color{purple}{b} = \color{purple}{3x}$. This gives $f(-3x)f(3x) = -3 f(-3x+3x)$ which is why there's a $-3$ at the front of the integral, it came from  this step.

Comment: If there's a typo with $35$, the steps will be the same but some of the numbers will change. But if you follow correctly you should get the right result. And lastly, yes, there is a problem with $f(x) >0$ as I explain at the start of my question. I would suggest you double-check the source of this problem to see what was the intention of the problem maker.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand better now the solution.